# tornado rise An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: windows, tornado

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tornado_runner.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File "tornado_runner.py", line 15, in main
    IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 858, in start
    event_pairs = self._impl.poll(poll_timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\select.py", line 63, in poll
    self.read_fds, self.write_fds, self.error_fds, timeout)
select.error: (10038, 'An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

it looks like the issue was solved for a while now,  https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1360
But for last few days i started to see  a lot of such errors in production windows environment. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue with yours, and I searched it everywhere but can't find any solution in code layer.
Finally, I tried to reset winsock in my Windows, by running "netsh winsock reset" in command line, and it works.

Comment: good for you, i read on tornado docs that windows is not supported platform, so i gave up at this point.